# Excel cell color formatting

Tags: excel

I want to make a cell color according to a datasheet. For example, I have table like this:

```
O | OK
X | Error
S | Slow
U | Unchecked
```

Then I have another table, valued like this:

```
D2.1 | U
D2.2 | X
D2.3 | X
D2.4 | S
D2.5 | O
```

And, I want have a map, such as this:

```
Room 1
D2.1 |      
D2.2 | D2.3       

Room 2
D2.4 | D2.5
```

Now, I need to color that D2.1 at the map so that they represent their status according to Table 2. I have figured out using Index and column, but I need to make it something like in conditional formatting:

```
=Switch(Index(Status[ID], Match(X1, Status[Status],0)), "O", "Green", "X", "Red", "S", "Yellow", "U", "White")
```

Is that possible?

Thank you for your help

Comment: This is indeed a case for conditional formatting. Set one fill colour as "no colour" and establish 3 rules to apply another colour, along the lines of `=IF(A3="X")` Then fill colour = Red and stop processing further rules for this cell.

Comment: So we cannot just define the color, and set it programmatically?

Comment: To do that you would require VBA

Comment: Can you give an example as answer? Because the colors are not always that, and if possible, I want to pick the color from the table, too. That would make my life much easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code must be installed in the code sheet of the worksheet on which you have the room map. The range RoomMap is defined here as A28:E32 and might be changed to encompass your table. Note that the code needs a named range "Status" which could be replaced with one of your other existing tables.

Please observe the comments in the code.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    ' 18 Oct 2017

    Dim RoomMap As Range
    Dim Stat As String                      ' new value (after change)
    Dim Cols()                              ' array of available colours
    Dim Col As Long                         ' selected colour

    ' Any cell in RoomMap will be coloured when changed.
    ' You can specify the range in any way a range can be specified.
    Set RoomMap = Range(Cells(28, "A"), Cells(32, "E"))

    ' ====================================================
    ' For the purpose of this test I have set up a Named Range
    ' called "Status", containing the letters O X S U.
    ' Each of the cells in RoomMap has Data Validation,
    ' also referring to the "Status" range,
    ' limiting entry to one of these letters or blank.
    ' ====================================================

    ' ====================================================
    ' The Cols() array contains Long values:
    '       vbBlue (0) = 16711680
    '       vbGreen (1) = 65280
    '       vbRed (2) = 255
    '       vbYellow (3) = 65535
    '       vbWhite (4) = 16777215
    ' They are matched to the sequence of letters in "Status"
    ' with (0) added to mark cells left blank

    ' You can replace the constant names with their numeric values.
    ' To define another colour, set the colour as fill in any cell,
    ' select the cell and write the following code in the Immediate window:-
    ' ? ActiveCell.Interior.Colour
    ' upon enter, the selected colour's number will be displayed.
    ' ====================================================


    If Not Application.Intersect(RoomMap, Target) Is Nothing Then
        Cols = Array(vbBlue, vbGreen, vbRed, vbYellow, vbWhite)
        With Target
            Stat = Trim(.Value)
            On Error Resume Next
            ' an error will occur if the cell doesn't have one
            ' of the values in "Status"
            ' The setting of Data Validation in the cell prevents
            ' any alternative value other than blank.
            Col = Application.Match(Target.Value, Range("Status"), 0)
            .Interior.Color = Cols(Col)
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Ah.. Ok.. Interior.Color. Nice. This is what I need. I will put those color legend in another table along with their status.
Thank you

Comment: Yes. I understand the code. Will make some adjustments to fit my need, but this is the piece I was missing. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Here is the example for you to use `Conditional Formatting` and you just need to set it up once and it will work quite nicely for you, and here is how you do it:

1. From my example, highlight `cell G3`, and then go to `Home > Conditional Formatting > New Rule > Use a formula ...` and enter the formula below and pick the `Fill` color you want (Please note you will need to adjust your range accordingly or just use a `named range` so it will be easier to manage in the future).

   `=VLOOKUP(G3,$D$3:$E$7,2,0)="X"`

[image]

2. Do the same thing for the other two colors and here are the formulas for you to use:

   Yellow: `=VLOOKUP(G3,$D$3:$E$7,2,0)="S"`

   Green: `=VLOOKUP(G3,$D$3:$E$7,2,0)="O"`

   So at the end, you should have something like this below:

[image]

3. Change the `Applies to` fields to `=$G$3:$H$6` or the range you would like to use.  Click `Apply` or `OK` and you should get the results you want.

Comment: Yes, but the problem is, that its status are not always that. I can be added to the table. I prefer to "vlookup" the color too  the other guy suggesting using VBA, and I thought I would need VBA too for this purpose, and set up from an array.

Comment: VBA maybe a better way.  But a second thought about the `VLOOKUP` formula used here, you can simply change the `X, S, O` point to a cell such as `=VLOOKUP(G3,$D$3:$E$7,2,0)=$A$1` so that way you can always change the status code.  It is up to you.